# Get dynamic key from union of interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access dateOfBirth property but i have to cast it to any in order to work. Because it is present in one of the interfaces not both of them. Any help

```
interface TestA {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

interface TestB {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
}

type TestC = TestA | TestB

const getDateOfBirth = (user: TestC) => {
    // Once i cast it's working but i lose all typescript here
   // I want somehow dynamically to tell typescript that this exists
    return (user as any).dateOfBirth;
}
 
const user1: TestB = {
    id: '123',
    name: 'u1s',
    dateOfBirth: new Date()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`user` could also be of `TestA`, where `dateOfBirth` does not exist. Hence you could check, if `dateOfBirth` is specified by using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#relational_operators):

```
const getDateOfBirth = (user: TestC): Date | undefined => {
  return 'dateOfBirth' in user ? user.dateOfBirth : undefined;
};
```